# .NET Core Web API Application cannot connect to SQL server running on Docker

Tags: c#, sql-server, macos, docker, asp.net-core-3.1

Using MAC. Error (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

```
Connection string "Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;User id=sa;Password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Using .NET Core 3.1. The Web API is running in a container

The database is running on docker container. ports mapped 1433:1433 Able to query the database from Azure Data Studio. But while trying to connect from .net.core application it giving me that error above.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

So, tried with the ip of the container "Server=172.17.0.2,1433;..." but the error persists.

**EDIT2 - Solution**

So, the docker-compose solved the issue, inserted the settings for slq running in docker.

Comment: Is the .NET Core app also running in a container? What does `docker ps -a` show?

Comment: yes, also in a container 0.0.0.0:22443->443/tcp

Comment: How are you making that link? Basically, `localhost` doesn't mean what you think it means in a container. You need to be able to resolve the other container by name, and reference that in your connstring

Comment: can you connect to the container using SSMS?

Comment: "Server=172.17.0.2,1433;..", so, tried with the ip of the container but the error persists...

Comment: Can you add the commands you’re using to start the two containers?

Comment: to extend on what superstator's comment is asking, do you use docker-compose or an orchestrator to run both of these containers?  also, edit and include all of this information into your question.  The point here is to make it answerable.

Comment: docker-compose solved the issue. But strange that even when pointing the sql ip and port without docker compose .net didn't want to connect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the container by name. You could do something like this

```
sql-data:
   environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "5433:1433" # Important: In a production environment, you should be using a managed service



- ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=sql-data;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

Comment: can you cite where you got this information? also, are you refering to a docker-compose.yml file here?