# .NET Core API not connecting to SQL Server running on Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

I have this error when trying to execute request to my Rest API running on Docker:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An
> internal exception was caught)  --->
> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException
> (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known

This is my connection string:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=sqlserver,1433;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=False;ConnectRetryCount=0;User Id=sa;Password=Password3784"
  }
}
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  test:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Test/Dockerfile

  sqlserverService:  
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest  
    hostname: 'sqlserver'  
    environment:  
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y  
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password3784"  
    volumes:  
      - ./data/mssql:/var/opt/mssql3  
    ports:  
      - '1433:1433'  
    expose:  
      - 1433
```

Using SQL Server Management Studio on my computer login with this credentials works fine.
localhost,1433
sa
Password3784

Comment: `ports` already exposes ports to containers in the swarm so `expose` seems redundant. Does it improve if you only use ports 1433:1433?

Comment: Does it work by IP?

Comment: I already removed the ports 1433:1433 but no change. @AlwaysLearning

Comment: How can I know the IP stablished by Docker? This is my first time using it. @RandyinMarin

Comment: duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909456/net-core-web-api-application-cannot-connect-to-sql-server-running-on-docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weel, I found the solution.

I was creating a new image with a SQL Server separatly from my API.

What I should do is create the SQL Server on the same docker-compose.

For that I have read this article (it's in spanish):
https://dev.to/ebarrioscode/que-demonios-es-docker-docker-compose-y-como-dockerizar-dotnet-core-webapi-y-sql-server-en-un-ambiente-de-desarrollo-ideal-95a

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this is just to add your localhost IP address or Server IP like:

```
Server=192.168.0.12\\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Database=x;Trusted_Connection=False; User Id=x;Password=x;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

With the connection string in your appsettings.json like this it should work fine.